# Using getElementById in Angular return undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular9

for simplicity, I remove the unnecessary code.

Already tried with **ngAfterViewInit** and **ngOnChanges** and still **this.chart** is undefined.

**.html**

```
<div class="chartContainer">
  <canvas id="chart" class="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.drawChart();
}
drawChart() {
    this.chart = document.getElementById("chart");
    console.log(this.chart);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal, reproducible example (eg. Stackblitz)? If you get the same result in `ngAfterViewInit()` hook, then it isn't clear where the issue is.

Comment: I create a stackblitz example and it's working fine and I just literally copy-paste the code from my project.

Comment: in stackblitz it's working even when I put in ngOnInit

Comment: Yeah I would not trust stackblitzes runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) a binding:

html

```
<div class="chartContainer">
  <canvas #chart id="chart" class="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

ts

```
@ViewChild('chart') chart: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>; // Might need to add { static: true } after 'chart;



ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.chart.nativeElement)
}
```

Comment: after 10 refreshes of the browser I successfully took 3 times the HTML element in ngAfterViewInit() method. I should investigate this more.

Answer (score 1):

Your should inject service to your component for call document.

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

export class YourComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: HTMLDocument) {
...
```